# How to write one line and nested 'if' statement without '?:' (is it possible?)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.9

Is it possible to write a one line `if-else` statement (i.e. only using one `;`) **without** using the `?:` expression? For instance something of the form:
    `if (p == 1) " " else "\n";`

Potential purpose could be:
    `cout << if (p == 1) " " else "\n";`

Just curious if this is possible, don't know if there are any practical applications for this.

Thanks

Comment: Packing as much code onto a single line as possible is not a good idea for "real" coding. Maybe it's interesting as an academic excercise, but on the job, code must be *readable* not *compact*.

Comment: Thanks for the response as you mentioned it was simply meant to be an academic exercise.

Comment: Why would the language have a feature identical to the  ternary when the ternary exists already?

Comment: An *academic exercise* that might get you question banned ...

Comment: What's with all the down votes against this question? Is there special badge for down voting legitimate questions?

Comment: Yeah not sure why all the downvotes. A lot of the answers are very interesting and educational. The question I hope was sufficiently compact and the answers provided certainly cleared up my misunderstandings.

Comment: calculamator, you can accept one of the 5 answers and bring this to close if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already used the two important words that are key to undestand why what you intend is not possible, but you probably haven't grasped their full meaning: [**Statement**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) and [**expression**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions).

The [`if` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (like *all* statements) does not yield a value, while the [`?:` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) is an expression that does yield a value.

Distinguishing between statements and expressions is a fundamental concept that is worth learning (check out the links in this answer and take your time!), not just for C++ but for almost all programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and yes this misunderstanding I think was the root of my question.

Comment: @calculamator The sad part is that I tried to help and be constructive, pointing you to the root problem in your understanding and help you learn and improve yourself. Result: Zero upvotes. (Not your fault). At the same time, a certain other answer got 13 upvotes (so far) while IMHO being just a destructive and impatient rant. These are the moments where I just can't understand the SO community. Nevermind, moving on... :)

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: I don't know about your background, but there are other programming languages where `if` is an expression, not a statement. I even know at least one language that has both an `if`-statement *and* an `if`-expression. This is why it is important to learn about concepts and paradigms so you can learn new languages much faster and better and with a much deeper understanding, far beyond the syntax itself.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful as my original misunderstanding was that `?:` was just another way to write an `if-else` statement (now know otherwise).  Also very interesting with other languages having an `if-else` statement as an expression, will keep this separation in mind when learning new languages. Also not too concerned with the downvotes as a majority of the answers are very high quality and my question and concerns were answered.

Answer (score 14):

You're asking "how do I do X, without using any of the tools the language provides to do X". It's silly.

And the answer's no. It's not possible.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I don't see the relevance of your trigraph/digraph tricks around `0[argv]`??

Comment: Yeah, that's not as obvious as I thought... I meant: *how to write a `[` without actually writing a `[`* ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Both of those things are "tools the language provides to do X" :P

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't address the general question, but it does work for the specific example you provided.

```
std::cout << " \n"[(bool)(p - 1)];
```

Explanation:

First, a string literal (such as `" \n"`) is an array. As such, it participates in pointer decay, and can be indexed just like any other pointer or array.

Second, an integer can be converted to a bool, and the conversion has the special property that a zero is converted to `false`, and anything else is converted to `true`. So when I subtract 1 from `p`, then convert it to bool, it is `false` if `p` is 1, and `true` otherwise.

Third, a bool can be (implicitly) converted back to an integer. `false` converts to 0, and `true` converts to 1. So converting from an int to a bool and back has the result that a 0 stays a 0, and anything else becomes a 1.

So, with those three points taken into consideration, the expression:

```
" \n"[(bool)(p - 1)]
```

results in one of these two possibilities:

```
" \n"[0]      // a space (if p == 1)
" \n"[1]      // or a newline (if p != 1)
```

I'd downvote this answer if I could.

Comment: wow..... that is a hack... please expand the why it works, just so people understand why it's such a hack.

Comment: It's more silly than a hack imo :P I like that it's inventive though.

Comment: Or equivalently, for even louder WTFs, `std::cout << ((bool)(p - 1))[" \n"];` :P

Comment: Disclaimer: please don't do this anywhere near production code... or any code

Comment: I might have used `!!(p - 1)` just for fun ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << [=]{ if (p == 1) return " "; else return "\n"; }();
```

Comment: _"i.e. using only one `;`"_ He didn't mean lexical lines.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit It fits the "potential purpose". Besides, I'm not making this code look like anything it's not. The OP can decide whether this meets their requirements.

Comment: I should of clarified this was meant as an _academic_ exercise and was curious of other ways to represent the `if-else` statement. Thanks for your response I have not seen that way before. (unfortunately can't upvote as do not have 15 reputation...)

Comment: Which is the shorter and more concise statement? A ternary operator, or using a lambda instead?

Answer (score 1):

Basically: no, it's not possible to do this:

```
cout << if (p == 1) " " else "\n";
```

That is exactly the purpose of `?:` operator - it yields value. Some things may not be possible with `if-else` syntax. Example: conditional initialization. Consider:

```
if(p == 1)
    int value = 1; //local variable!
else
    int value = 0; //and so is this one!

//here 'value' is unknown
```

Above problem could be solved this way:

```
int value; //default initialization

if(p == 1)
    value = 1; //assignment to already initialized variable!
else
    value = 0; //and so is this!
```

But these two are not equal. For some types, it may result in totally different behavior, because initialization is different from assignment. `?:` is a solution:

```
int value == (p == 1) ? 1 : 0; //'value' is initialized with value, that depends on 'p'
```

Do not try to do things without tools, that were designed to do that things for you.

Comment: One example where if-else can't substitute for the ternary conditional operator is when initializing a reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response this identifies my confusion motivating the original question.